# xcrun clang --sysroot can not find stdio.h

Tags: xcode, clang, xcrun

With Xcode 4.6, under Mac OS X 10.8.2, to compile hello.c, I issued the xcrun command recommended in [xcrun gcc cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838993/) but still received the error that the header file stdio.h can not be found.

```
 $ xcrun clang --sysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/ -o hello hello.c
 hello.c:2:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
 #include <stdio.h>
     ^
 1 error generated.
 $ cat hello.c
 /* C program, Hello World */
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  printf("Hello World \n");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

it should work with : 
xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `Build Settings` for that project as the `Base SDK` was not specified. Once I changed it to `OS X 10.7` (or whatever you are using should be fine), I was able to compile everything successfully without changing other build configurations.